# how to get the table total by adding the rows of that table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the table total by adding of that table rows based on the same id but here for the first table it's coming correctly but for the second table it's adding the first table total and displaying the sum.
How to avoid of adding that to the second table.
my HTML code:

```
<table>
  <tr style="background:#2b2e76">
    <th colspan="1" style="padding: 0;">
      <p style="color:white">
        Table One

      </p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p style="color:white" class="BundleB4936" id="B4936">Total : <span class="BundelRowTotalB4936">1400.00</span></p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="200.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal11_B4936" class="rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="1200.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal12_B4936" class=" rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr style="background:#2b2e76">
    <th colspan="1" style="padding: 0;">
      <p style="color:white">
        Table Two

      </p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p style="color:white" class="BundleB1027" id="B1027">Total : <span class="BundelRowTotalB1027">1750.00</span></p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="100.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal16_B1027" class="rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="250.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal17_B1027" class="rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

my jquery :

```
 var Bsum = 0;
    var BundelID = '';
    $(".rowTotal").each(function() {
      var RowID = $(this).attr('id');
      var suffix = RowID.match(/\d+/)[0];
      BundelID = $('.BundleB' + suffix).attr('id');

      if (RowID.indexOf(BundelID) != -1) {
        var BValue = $('#' + RowID).val();
        if (!isNaN(BValue)) {
          Bsum += parseFloat(BValue);
        }
      }
      $('.BundelRowTotal' + BundelID).html(parseFloat(Bsum).toFixed(2));

    });
```

Here the output what I m getting

[image]

But I want the output should be like below

[image]

Any suggestions Please!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a problem in you Ids Parse try this code instead of yours

Note -> the lines changed are commented.

**Updated**

```
 $("table").each(function() {
 var Bsum = 0;
  var BundelID = '';
$(this).find(".rowTotal").each(function() {

  var RowID = $(this).attr('id');
  //var suffix = RowID.match(/\d+/)[0];
  var suffix = RowID.split("_")[1];

  console.log(suffix)
  BundelID = $('.Bundle' + suffix).attr('id');
  console.log(BundelID);
  if (RowID.indexOf(BundelID) != -1) {
    var BValue = $('#' + RowID).val();
    if (!isNaN(BValue)) {
      Bsum += parseFloat(BValue);
    }
  }
  console.log(Bsum);
  $('.BundelRowTotal' + BundelID).html(parseFloat(Bsum).toFixed(2));

});
});
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cnFiSAwI9znbAyXvu08k?p=preview) is a working copy
Note-> I removed the Sums from the HTML and the Numbers are Calculated by the code

Comment: Code and Sample Updated Check it Hope this helps

Comment: Just checked with your code its taking only the last row of the table and adding . How its working for you ?

Comment: Yes perfect ! Thank you So much :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Iterate each table and then iterate input from each table to calcluate total value

```js
 $(function(){
       $('table').each(function(){
          var $totalRow = $(this).find('span[class^="BundelRowTotal"]');
          var total = 0.0;
          $(this).find('input.rowTotal').each(function(){
             total += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0.0;
          });
          $totalRow.html(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr style="background:#2b2e76">
    <th colspan="1" style="padding: 0;">
      <p style="color:white">
        Table One

      </p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p style="color:white" class="BundleB4936" id="B4936">Total : <span class="BundelRowTotalB4936">1400.00</span></p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="200.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal11_B4936" class="rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="1200.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal12_B4936" class=" rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr style="background:#2b2e76">
    <th colspan="1" style="padding: 0;">
      <p style="color:white">
        Table Two

      </p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p style="color:white" class="BundleB1027" id="B1027">Total : <span class="BundelRowTotalB1027"></span></p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="100.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal16_B1027" class="rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="250.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal17_B1027" class="rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var val1 = +$('#rowtotal11_B4936').val();
var val2 = +$('#rowtotal12_B4936').val();
$('.BundelRowTotalB4936').text(val1+val2);

var val3 = +$('#rowtotal16_B1027').val();
var val4 = +$('#rowtotal17_B1027').val();
$('.BundelRowTotalB1027').text(val4+val3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr style="background:#2b2e76">
    <th colspan="1" style="padding: 0;">
      <p style="color:white">
        Table One

      </p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p style="color:white" class="BundleB4936" id="B4936">Total : <span class="BundelRowTotalB4936"></span></p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="200.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal11_B4936" class="rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="1200.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal12_B4936" class=" rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr style="background:#2b2e76">
    <th colspan="1" style="padding: 0;">
      <p style="color:white">
        Table Two

      </p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p style="color:white" class="BundleB1027" id="B1027">Total : <span class="BundelRowTotalB1027">1750.00</span></p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="100.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal16_B1027" class="rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="250.00" name="row_total[]" id="rowtotal17_B1027" class="rowTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your snippet gives the same wrong result as the OP.

Comment: what you want the 2nd table to add only 2nd table value?

Comment: Check now, You want like this ?

Comment: Its not my question!

Comment: This can not be hard-coded as here all the ids are generating dynamically . Can you look for an alternative ?